# Get a User object from a ping using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

I want one of the commands for my discord bot to give a specific role to the user mentioned in the command. For example:
`!giveperm @Bob`

In this case Bob would be given a role. However the add_roles() function takes a discord.User object. Is there a way to turn a ping in a string format into a discord.User object. Something like: `discord.User(ping="{ping}")`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```py
@bot.command()
async def giveperm(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.send(user.id)
    #other code
```